# Send Forms Authentication Cookie with explicit samesite=none

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config, forms-authentication, samesite

I have been able to do this transition for the session cookie but not for the login cookie
[image]

and I have the following web.config

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="MyCookie" loginUrl="~/Login/login.aspx" timeout="30" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseCookies" cookieSameSite="None" protection="All" requireSSL="true" defaultUrl="~/Login/DefaultRedirect.aspx" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" path="/" />
    </authentication>
```

if I change `cookieSameSite="None"` to `cookieSameSite="Lax"` or strict. I can see that the change takes place, but it seems to still have the old behavior of not emiting the samesite value when set to None

I'm using .net framework 4.7.2 and have installed the server update that allowed me to do the session with samesite=none

Answer (score 5, accepted):

turn out I was missing `sameSite="None"` `<httpCookies`

so now I have : `<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" sameSite="None" />`

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="MyCookie" loginUrl="~/Login/login.aspx" timeout="30" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseCookies" cookieSameSite="None" protection="All" requireSSL="true" defaultUrl="~/Login/DefaultRedirect.aspx" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" path="/" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: Thankyour, you saved me! I've struggled maniy hours to find out that sameSite need to be set on booth forms and httpCookies